# How to handle patch method in AJAX?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

How to handle the patch method from AJAX. My backend is written in Django rest API.Im using model viewsets.Backend view as below:

```
class ProductAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      serializer_class = ProductSerializer
      queryset  = ProductTbl.objects.all()
      
      @action(detail=False, methods=['PATCH'])
      def get_object(self,*args,**kwargs):
          return get_object_or_404(**kwargs)

      def update_product(self,request,pk):
           try:
                 product_obj = self.get_obj(pk=pk)
                 serializer = self.serializer_class(product_obj,data = request.data,
                                              partial = True)
                if serializer.is_valid():
                    serializer.save()
                    return Response({},status = 200)
                return Response(serializer.errors,status = 400)
           except Exception as e:
                return Response({},status = 500)
```

urls.py

```
 path('product/edit/<int:pk>/', ProductAPI.as_view({'patch': 'update_product'}), name='update_products'),
```

my ajax code as follows:

```
    var form = new FormData($("#update_form")[0])
    $.ajax({
    type:"PATCH",
    url : "/product/edit/1",
    data:form,
    success:function(data){

    },
    error:function(data){

   }
})
```

Still, I'm getting error 405.Method not allowed...

Comment: Set `detail=True`.

Comment: but detail param can be used to return a single object. how details = false will be incorrect? @Guillaume

Comment: What do you exactly want to do ? Patch is for partially updating an instance, so I would use the action decorator on the `update_product`  method and set `detail=True` because it's about one single object ("/product/edit/1", and not "/product/")